# Atomic Layer Deposition

Tags: solid-state-physics, nanoscience

What is "conformality" in atomic layer deposition?

As in 
1. "recombination of radicals on the sidewalks limits the conformality in high aspect ratio structures" 
Or in 
2. "Key advantage of ALD is to deposit conformally into high AR structures“

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conformality means that the deposited thin film follows the shape of the substrate.

Comment: I was under the impression it means shape on an atomic scale. That is the crystal structure of the film aligns with the crystal structure of the substrate. E.G. the interatomic distance for the film might normally be different from the substrate. For a very thin film, film atoms might be attracted to sites in the substrate's crystal structure, stretching or compressing the film horizontally. For a thicker film, the film's crystal structure might assert itself and conformality might be lost. But I am not sure of this. Can anyone tell me if it is true?

Comment: @mmesser314 : "Conformality is an indication of the ability of the film-deposition process to coat the surfaces of undercut recesses as well as the top and side wall surfaces.
From: Encyclopedia of Materials: Science and Technology, 2001" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/conformality)